# Missing highlighting solution for iOS 5

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5

I am wondering whether there is an alternative solution to access the moment when this happens. 
For iOS 6 SDK we have `tableView:didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:`

But I am bound by the project specs which is iOS 5.

Any advice?